# Entity Framework 1 to 0 relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Tecnologies: ASP.NET MVC3, Entity Framework 4, Multi-tier App

I have two tables in 0 to 1 relationship. A duplicata's can have 0 or one pagamento, and pagamento only have one duplicata. [Link](http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/9977/xzyh.jpg)

The Duplicata's row is saved im my database, when I creates a new Pagameto entity and add to one Dupliacata  gives this erro:

```
 A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.
```

The image Bellow display the entity Duplicata with one Pagamento.
[Link](http://imageshack.us/f/194/9fmu.jpg/)

And the code with gets error:

```
            context.Duplicata.Attach(duplicata);
            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(duplicata, EntityState.Modified);

            context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Why do you use attach? Did you detach the entity previously? Because if saving is what you want to do, try using .AddObject method instead

Comment: I use attach because the duplicata already exist in my database. In this case, i add a pagamento to duplicata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but the porpouse of attach is not adding the element to the duplicata bu to get into the context a detached entity. If you want to create a new duplicata just create a new one. Like in

```
// just for testing NO magic numbers!
var pagamentoId = 1;
var duplicata = new Duplicata();
duplicata.PAGAMENTO_ID = pagamentoId;
duplicata.VALOR = 1000;
duplicata.CLIENTE_ID = 23;

// add the rest of properties


// then...
context.AddObject("Duplicatas", duplicata);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Note I used "Duplicatas" in the addobject as I assumed that is your name for the Duplicata set (set means it's a collection of Duplicata and you set that name in the EDMX file).

By setting the pagamento_id to the value you want it automatically generates the relationship between both entities

Comment: But my problem is when i created a Pagamento, and add the pagamento to any Duplicata.

Comment: But, per your db design, duplicata depends on pagamento (duplicata is the parent of pagamento) and the relationship is done between dbo.pagamento.id and dbo.duplicata.pagamento_id. If this is not the case, and pagamento is the parent, you have to redesign the db. So if what I say is correct, you have to create pagamento first and the add a duplicata to it.

Comment: So it was a mistake in the design of the db. I need that Pagamento depends the Duplicata, not otherwise.

Than i need is redo the relationship between Duplicata and Pagamento and the duplicata.pagamento.add(Pagamento) will works correct?

Comment: It should, but I prefer using the context.AddObject() instead of entityObject.Add(). I find it easier to read.